# What is the best way to find all pairs in a list with a given condition?

Tags: python, algorithm

Say I have a list `['ab','cd','ac','de']` and I want to find all possible pairs where both elements do not have any repeating letter.

The answer would be `['ab','cd'],['ab','de'],['ac','de']`.

But I do not know the best possible way/algorithm to solve this. Currently what I am doing is using a nested `for` loop to check with each element and then removing it to shorten the list, but when my list is 1000s of lines long and the elements more complicated, it starts to take a noticeable amount of time.

```
arr4 = ['ab','cd','ac','de']
for i in arr4:
    for x in arr4:
        if not bool(set(i)&set(x)):
            print('['+i+','+x+']')
    print('----')
    arr4.remove(i)
```

Comment: What does "elements more complicated" mean?

Comment: Don't know if it's the "best", but you could check the length of a set composed of the letters in each pair. If it's shorter than the total number of letters, there were duplicates.

Comment: Also you could save half the time by only checking  `x` with `index(x) > index(i)`

Comment: @martineau That sounds worse than what they already have...

Comment: And modifying a list while iterating over it is generally a bad idea...

Comment: @KellyBundy It means the elements might have 3 or 4 letters, but now that i think about it i guess it will make a negligible difference for comparing. but all the elements in the list will always have the same number of letters.

Comment: And are the "letters" always from the 26 letters 'a' to 'z'?

Comment: @KellyBundy yes it uses the english alphabet

Comment: What is the desired result if the list were `['ab', 'cd', 'cd']`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland the list will never have duplicated elements where the letters have the same order, but i guess if it were to happen it would be ['ab','cd']. a list where both 'cd' and 'dc' might exist though and the desired results for that would be ['ab,'cd'],['ab','dc']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution isn't bad, as far as the basic algorithm goes, but you shouldn't modify the list you're iterating over like you do. Also, there's some optimisation possible:

```
from random import sample
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import combinations


size = 3  # length of the strings
chars = [chr(n) for n in range(97, 123)]
strings = {''.join(sample(chars, size)) for _ in range(1000)}


# your solution as a one-liner
def pair_strs1(ps):
    return [(p, q) for p in ps for q in ps if not (set(p) & set(q))]


# this doesn't work, unless there's no initial pairs with double letters like 'aa'
def pair_strs2(ps):
    return [(p, q) for p in ps for q in ps if len(set(p+q)) == 4]


# your solution, but compute the sets only once, then look them up before combining
def pair_strs3(ps):
    ps = {p: set(p) for p in ps}
    return [(p, q) for p in ps for q in ps if not (ps[p] & ps[q])]


# same, but avoiding mirrored pairs, only compute above the diagonal of the product
def pair_strs4(ps):
    ps = {p: set(p) for p in ps}
    keys = list(ps.keys())
    return [(p, q) for i, p in enumerate(ps) for q in keys[i+1:] if not (ps[p] & ps[q])]


# the same again, but now avoiding the lookup in the dictionaries
def pair_strs5(ps):
    ps = {p: set(p) for p in ps}
    items = list(ps.items())
    return [(p, q) for i, (p, p_set) in enumerate(ps.items()) for q, q_set in items[i+1:] if not (p_set & q_set)]


# different approach, creating the product (upper half above diagonal) first
def pair_strs6(ps):
    ps = {p: set(p) for p in ps}
    ps = combinations(ps.items(), 2)
    return [(p, q) for (p, p_set), (q, q_set) in ps if not (p_set & q_set)]


# the same as 5, but with integer bitmasks instead of sets, as per @kellybundy's suggestion
def pair_strs7(ps):
    ps = {p: sum(1 << (ord(c) - 97) for c in p) for p in ps}
    items = list(ps.items())
    return [(p, q) for i, (p, p_mask) in enumerate(ps.items()) for q, q_mask in items[i+1:] if not (p_mask & q_mask)]


# run some tests
n = 10
print(timeit(lambda: pair_strs1(strings), number=n))
print(timeit(lambda: pair_strs3(strings), number=n))
print(timeit(lambda: pair_strs4(strings), number=n))
print(timeit(lambda: pair_strs5(strings), number=n))
print(timeit(lambda: pair_strs6(strings), number=n))
print(timeit(lambda: pair_strs7(strings), number=n))


p1 = pair_strs1(strings)
p3 = pair_strs3(strings)
p4 = pair_strs4(strings)
p4 += [tuple(reversed(p)) for p in p4]
p5 = pair_strs5(strings)
p5 += [tuple(reversed(p)) for p in p5]
p6 = pair_strs6(strings)
p6 += [tuple(reversed(p)) for p in p6]
p7 = pair_strs7(strings)
p7 += [tuple(reversed(p)) for p in p7]

print(set(p1) == set(p3) == set(p4) == set(p5) == set(p6) == set(p7) and
      len(p1) == len(p3) == len(p4) == len(p5) == len(p6) == len(p7))
```

Result for me:

```
3.4115294000002905
1.7107413000012457
0.8492871999987983
0.7485178000024462
0.7776397999987239
0.37149049999788986
True
```

So, the final change doesn't really help - computing the product beforehand doesn't save enough. `pair_pairs5` appears to be preferable.

Edit: changed the generation of strings to including a size (and set the default to 3 instead of 2), adjusted naming accordingly and avoiding duplicate characters in strings (as per OP's description).

This also makes user @KellyBundy's solution the fastest, since the lack of duplicates allows for a very clean integer-based solution, #7. This is the clear winner under these conditions (about a 9x speed-up).

Comment: Easy optimization: remove the `bool` calls.

Comment: Ints are faster: `ps = {p: sum(1 << (ord(c) - 97) for c in p) for p in ps}`

Comment: Wow thats a pretty big optimazation, may i know what algorithms they are called if any?

Comment: @kellybundy It was mainly bad because it allows duplicates, but it does make sense to use a greater size, to allow for a larger testset, so I did add that as well. Disallowing duplicates makes your solution the fastest, so I added it.

Comment: @guyguy I don't think these solutions have names - they are just piecing together very common patterns you would use in everyday programming. The fastest solution ends up using a bitwise and, by making clever use of a shift operator to have the letters in each string represented by individual bits (i.e. bit n being 1 means the corresponding character is in the string). In the end, the fastest solution is about 8x faster than your own.

Comment: "Your solution isn't bad" — Yes, it is; not because of the performance, but because it skips elements (due to removing items during iteration), as noted by Julien.

Comment: I don't think they ruled out duplicate letters inside one string, you could make the int-solution handle that with `for c in set(p)` (I think I tested that and it didn't make a speed difference) or xor-ing instead of adding. Your edit removing the `bool` calls didn't update the times, were the times already done without the `bool` calls and you had just forgotten to update the code in the previous edit?

Comment: Correct - a copy/paste error on my part, although there will be some variation anyway of course, the times were without the `bool()` there. (however, rerunning now, I'm getting better times, so just to be sure replacing the times with a fresh set) From OP's question: "all possible pairs where both elements do not have any repeating letter", so I take that to mean the original strings don't have repeating letters to begin with.

Comment: Hmm, I think they meant "common" there. Anyway, not a big deal. About variation/bool: Yes, there's variation, but the effect of the bool calls is much bigger, at least for the fast solutions. Tried your `pair_strs5` now with and without it, three times each, alternatingly. With the call it took 1.65, 1.62 and 1.69 seconds. Without, it took 1.25, 1.26 and 1.16 seconds.

Comment: @Amadan I missed that (I mainly meant my implementation of the same idea, which doesn't have that issue - but thanks for pointing that out)

Comment: @KellyBundy - agreed, I see the same. The current solution is completely in line with the result and I think we can leave it here.

Comment: Yes, I don't see much further improvement potential with this approach (checking all pairs).

Comment: [Another algorithm](https://tio.run/##dZDNagMxDITv@xQ6etOwh/QSAvskIRRjy41h11JlpdC@/EbZnzaX6GIYzXwjzD96pfJ@ZJmmJDRCoGHAoJlKhTwyiULE5G@Dxhy0mT1ZUZRo@HMIMnptGnMC@ywfVaUeHdf21IBNODD0zxxXUdt5lUiAIRfgung3Mcziv7ZyzuHS@RgdL3HB0ZuvBwM@@laxWo@J58vrjiXZ2UPfuOEe81UtuW5jTgkFS0C3Gz07O6D7RN0Dt@0Taa576@E3s1v@woB7I2336E3K6pumOw). In my testing, it's faster than `pair_strs5` but slower than `pair_strs7`, so not very interesting. But the times on my system are quite different from yours, so I'm curious, where does it fall for you?

Comment: I think it shows the limitations of the test set - depending on the starting set, it's often a bit slower (a few percent), sometimes actually faster. Biggest difference I saw was .36 to .27 - but I didn't capture the test set that was running against. If this was to be used in a production setting, it might be worth analysing how the algorithms perform against actual production data, but for OP's purposes, I would still recommend #7.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, actual production data would make it more interesting to dive deeper.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could track the letter set for each array element. Then, store the reversed pair(e.g., (x,i)) not to visit the entry again as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr4 = ['ab','cd','ac','de']
    string_dict = {}
    for a_str in arr4:
        if a_str not in string_dict:
            string_dict[a_str] = set()
        for a_letter in a_str:
            string_dict[a_str].add(a_letter)
    print(string_dict)
    visited = set()
    for i in arr4:
        for x in arr4:
            if not (string_dict[i] & string_dict[x]):
                cur_pair = (i, x)
                if cur_pair in visited:
                    continue
                print(cur_pair)
                reverse_pair = (x, i)
                visited.add(cur_pair)
                visited.add(reverse_pair)
```

Result:

```
{'ab': {'a', 'b'}, 'cd': {'c', 'd'}, 'ac': {'a', 'c'}, 'de': {'d', 'e'}}
('ab', 'cd')
('ab', 'de')
('ac', 'de')
```